# What does the error "IRE!" mean in GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

I am working on a C++ program for a class, and GDB keeps reporting `IRE!`and giving no other useful output. With some tweaking I get a seg. fault, but nothing else. There doesn't seem to be any mention of this particular output in the GNU documentation or from Google, so I'd thought I'd ask here.

**What does `IRE!` mean in the context of GDB output, and what typically is the cause/error behind it?**

Comment: What is your OS, GDB version, and C++ compiler version?

Comment: Are you working on anything related to radio or wireless?

Comment: The latest Ubuntu, GCC 4.7 , GDB 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The string "IRE!" does not appear in the gdb sources.

You didn't mention your gdb version.  Maybe it is some vendor modification (though it seems unlikely).

You also didn't show your session.  Odds are it is coming from your program, not gdb.